# Select all alias on modifySSLConfig using JACL script

Tags: ssl, websphere, jacl

I would want to edit all of the SSL configurations on all of my alias. I have found some resources to do this and my code so far is

```
$AdminTask modifySSLConfig {-alias NodeDefaultSSLSettings -sslProtocol TLSv1.2}
$AdminConfig save
```

I would want to be able to do this on all of the alias that can be found on my server, but I don't know how

Any ideas or leads on how to do this will help. Thank you.

Edit:

I am now able to find all of the SSL configs by using this code

```
[$AdminTask listSSLConfigs {-scopeName (cell):Node01Cell:(node):Node01}
```

My next problem is, how would I be able to extract the alias string from there? I would only need the alias so that I can replace it on another variable so that I can just use a foreach loop for this

```
$AdminTask modifySSLConfig {-alias ${aliasvariablegoeshere}  -sslProtocol TLSv1.2}
```

EDIT :

```
set hold [list [$AdminTask listSSLConfigs {-scopeName (cell):Node01Cell:(node):Node01}]]
foreach aliasList [$AdminConfig show $hold] {
    foreach aliasName [$AdminConfig show $aliasList] {
        set testTrim "alias "
        set test5 [string trimleft $aliasName $testTrim]
        $AdminTask modifySSLConfig {-alias ${test5} -sslProtocol TLSv1.2}
    }
}
$AdminControl save
```

I have done this and was able to extract just the alias name and was able to put it on the variable like I wanted, but it gives me an invalid parameter error. Any ideas why this is happening and how would I be able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work, it seems like whatever I do I can't make the alias that I got to be a valid parameter so I made the whole thing as a string command instead. Here is my code.

```
foreach aliasList [$AdminConfig list SSLConfig] {
    foreach aliasName [$AdminConfig show $aliasList alias] {
        set strTrim "alias "
        set strFinal [string trimleft $aliasName $strTrim]
        set command "-alias $strFinal -sslProtocol TLSv1.2"
        $AdminTask modifySSLConfig $command
        puts saved
    }
}
$AdminConfig save
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the SSL configs using:

```
AdminTask.listSSLConfigs('[-all true]')
```

for JACL use:

```
$AdminTask listSSLConfigs {-all true}
```

and then iterate over the list and change whatever you need. 
Instead of `-all` you can provide scope for example: `-scopeName (cell):localhostNode01Cell:(node):localhostNode01`

For details about SSLConfig commands check [SSLConfigCommands command group for the AdminTask object](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_atsslconfig.html#rxml_atsslconfig__cmd7)

UPDATE:

in general this should work:

```
foreach aliasList [$AdminTask listSSLConfigs {-scopeName (cell):PCCell1:(node):Node1}] {
    puts $aliasList  
    set splitList [split $aliasList " "]
    puts $splitList 
    set aliasname [lindex $splitList 1]
    puts $aliasname

    $AdminTask modifySSLConfig { -alias $aliasname -sslProtocol TLSv1.2 }

}
```

but I cannot make `$AdminTask` to correctly resolve `$aliasname` param...
Strongly suggest you to switch to jython. ;-)

Comment: I did something similar to that, here it is
     $AdminTask listSSLConfigs {-scopeName (cell):cellName:(node):nodeName}

my next problem is how do I extract the alias name from there? I am thinking of passing that to a variable and use that for 

     $AdminTask modifySSLConfig {-alias ${thatvariablegoeshere}  -sslProtocol TLSv1.2}

Comment: since alias is a required parameter, im not sure how to apply it on all of the ssl configs since they have different aliases. i would want to apply it to all of them.

Comment: yes, that's also the issue where I got stuck. I made the command after modifySSLConfig as a string command and it surprisingly worked. thank you Gas.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out for Jython:

```
import sys
import os
import string
import re

#$HOME/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f $HOME/tls12.py
#Updates Websphere security to TLSv1.2

AdminTask.convertCertForSecurityStandard('[-fipsLevel SP800-131 -signatureAlgorithm SHA256withRSA -keySize 2048 ]')
AdminConfig.save()
AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()

sslConfigList=AdminTask.listSSLConfigs('[-all true]').splitlines()
for sslConfig in sslConfigList:
  sslElems=sslConfig.split(" ")
  AdminTask.modifySSLConfig (['-alias',sslElems[1],'-scopeName',sslElems[3],'-sslProtocol', 'TLSv1.2', '-securityLevel', 'HIGH' ])

AdminConfig.save()
AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()
```

After that you should also update all your ssl.client.props files with:

```
com.ibm.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

Restart your deployment manager and force manual syncNode on all nodes, for example:

```
~/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/*/bin/syncNode.sh <DeplymentManagerHost> <dmgr port=8879> -username <username> -password <password>
```